# What is this symbol's name?

Tags: notation

I'm reading it in a pdf and I have tried to copy and paste it into Google with no luck and IDK what to search for. Thanks

[image]

Comment: In MathJax, Tex, etc. it’s `\gamma` $\gamma$, and in Unicode it’s `U+03B3` γ (or `U+1D6FE` for the mathematical version)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a lower case gamma, from the Greek alphabet.

Comment: duh...I looked through the greeks and I missed it....Thanks

Comment: All good! If you do maths long enough you'll know the whole Greek alphabet

Comment: @Motmot And some Hebrew